# truncated sound clips on IOS

Tags: ios, audio, codenameone

The essence of the problem is that on IOS only, playing 
sound clips using

MediaManager.createMedia(clip, "audio/wav", null).play();

sometimes the playback is truncated.  This is especially obvious
when the clip is several seconds long, but the point at which the
clip is truncated varies; occasionally the whole clip plays.

I've so far been unsuccessful creating a simple test case - in isolation
from my apps, the clip plays in full, so it seems like something in normal
background activity in the full app is interfering with audio playback.

Comment: Is it possible another audio clip is playing and impacting it? What's `clip`? Is it a stream? Is it possible someone is closing it?

Comment: no other clips are played, and the stream can be a private ByteArrayInputstream, it makes no difference.

Comment: We'll need a way to reproduce this. I don't see anything that jumps out as risky in the iOS implementation of these API's in a cursory review

Comment: One additional clue; the "oncomplete" action is not occurring for the truncated sounds.  This suggests that the missing sound is still in the data queue, and maybe there's a race condition in the process that feeds data to the native sound player.

Comment: Maybe it's something in `AudioPlayer.m` where one of the callbacks that's ignored triggers this. There are several callbacks we don't map at the moment like `audioPlayerEndInterruption` & `audioPlayerBeginInterruption` might be something related to that. If you can reproduce this on xcode it might be more obvious

Comment: It's a bit deep in the VM for me to make a meaningful investigation in xcode.  It's trivial to reproduce from my full app - I could supply or give you permission to copy an xcode source.

Comment: It's just setting a breakpoint and seeing what gets hit. It isn't the VM its the native port code which is relatively simple. You can see the methods of the callback in the implementation invoked from there if one of the blank error callbacks is invoked that's probably the issue. You can add an `NSLog` printout of the error to see what's happening

Comment: None of the dummy callbacks that are in audioplayer.m are called.   Curiously, the "stop" and "destroy" callbacks are also never used.  OTOH the "pauseAudio" callback is used once per sound clip, successful or not.   Perhaps some cleanup code is being invoked prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've found the root cause.  MediaManager.createMedia creates an instance of Media, and when that object is garbage collected, it's finalize method is called, and a side effect of that causes the audio to be stopped.

A quick and dirty way to prevent this is to save a pointer to the media object.
This ought to be accomplished by internal bookkeeping in playaudio.

Comment: You can probably file an issue on that. It might be something we can address